# How can I programmatically remove text from a ReadOnly RichTextBox?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

The following code aims to maintain a text buffer in a `ReadOnly` RichTextBox, with a maximum number of characters stored, and always kept scrolled to the bottom. It streams a realtime log.

But in my attempt to maintain the maximum character count, `rtMessages.TextLength()` isn't changing after `rtMessages.SelectedText = String.Empty` and consequently, without the defensive `If` block, I'd end up with an infinite loop attempting to repeatedly delete the first line of the buffer.

When I remove the `ReadOnly`-ness of the `RichTextBox`, this functionality succeeds. Seems a little strange, since `AppendText` succeeds, but I understand that selection is a different beast.

**Can I make it so that a `ReadOnly` `RichTextBox` is *programmatically* modifiable?**

```
Private Sub onNewData(ByRef data As String) Handles _server.clientSentData

    ' Add new text
    rtMessages.SelectionStart = rtMessages.TextLength()
    rtMessages.AppendText(data)

    ' Delete oldest text line-by-line until the whole buffer is shorter than MAX_TEXT_LENGTH characters
    Const MAX_TEXT_LENGTH = 200
    Dim textLength = rtMessages.TextLength()
    While textLength > MAX_TEXT_LENGTH
        Dim i As Int16 = 0
        Do While rtMessages.GetLineFromCharIndex(i) < 1
            i += 1
        Loop

        rtMessages.Select()
        rtMessages.SelectionStart = 0
        rtMessages.SelectionLength = i
        rtMessages.SelectedText = String.Empty
        rtMessages.SelectionLength = 0

        If rtMessages.TextLength() = textLength Then
            rtMessages.Clear()
            rtMessages.AppendText("[buffer trimming algorithm failed]")
            Exit While
        End If

        textLength = rtMessages.TextLength()
    End While

    ' Scroll down
    rtMessages.SelectionStart = rtMessages.TextLength()
    rtMessages.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

Comment: I can confirm that this `Sub` is being invoked on the UI thread, not some comms thread.

Comment: +1 because the problem isn't as simple as it looks like...  I'm surpise no one mentionned this on SO before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While trying to replace SelectedText in a ReadOnly RichTextBox doesn't work, using the SelectedRtf does work:

```
  'rtMessages.Select()
  'rtMessages.SelectionStart = 0
  'rtMessages.SelectionLength = i
  'rtMessages.SelectedText = String.Empty
  'rtMessages.SelectionLength = 0

  rtMessages.Select(0, i)
  rtMessages.SelectedRtf = "{\rtf1\ansi}"
```

Comment: Would I end up with a ton of `{\rtf1\ansi}` codepoints at the start of the buffer, or will they collapse/be elided?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They will be elided.  The RTB "merges" the RTF documents.

Comment: Well there we go then :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
rtMessages.SelectionLength = i - 1
```

Should be replaced by

```
rtMessages.SelectionLength = i
```

EDIT #1

By adding the -1 to the SelectionLength, you're missing the last character of the first line.  On the second run, only 1 character will be on the first line (the one you missed on the first run).  Then you will try to delete a SelectionLength of 0 and you'll get the same TextLength for every other runs and there you go with the infinite loop!

Comment: Are you sure?  I reproduced your bug on my side and changing this line did the trick for me.

Comment: When I make the code change the bug remains until I turn off `ReadOnly`. And every iteration gave me the same TextLength, not every iteration except the first.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you edit about the ReadOnly.  Well, the simple solution would be to set the RTB ReadOnly property to false, run your code and then set the ReadOnly back to True.  Here's an other post about the same problem: http://microsoftfaqs.com/msg/1440552.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the read-only parameter, write your appendtext code and then make the richtextbox readonly again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but you can get around the `ReadOnly` issue the replacing the following code:

```
 rtMessages.Select()
 rtMessages.SelectionStart = 0
 rtMessages.SelectionLength = i
 rtMessages.SelectedText = String.Empty
 rtMessages.SelectionLength = 0
```

with this:

```
 rtMessages.Text = rtMessages.Text.Substring(i)
```

I'm not sure if this is better or worse performance, but it gets around the `RichTextBox` being set as `ReadOnly`

Edit:

Here is the complete code used to test this (Note: I added the code to a `Button.Click` for testing)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static X As Integer = 0
    X += 1

    Dim Data As String = "Line " & X.ToString & ControlChars.NewLine
    Me.onNewData(Data)
End Sub

Private Sub onNewData(ByRef data As String)

    ' Add new text
    rtMessages.SelectionStart = rtMessages.TextLength()
    rtMessages.AppendText(data)

    ' Delete oldest text line-by-line until the whole buffer is shorter than MAX_TEXT_LENGTH characters
    Const MAX_TEXT_LENGTH As Integer = 200
    Dim textLength As Integer = rtMessages.TextLength()
    While textLength > MAX_TEXT_LENGTH
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While rtMessages.GetLineFromCharIndex(i) < 1
            i += 1
        Loop

        'rtMessages.Select()
        'rtMessages.SelectionStart = 0
        'rtMessages.SelectionLength = i
        'rtMessages.SelectedText = String.Empty
        'rtMessages.SelectionLength = 0

        rtMessages.Text = rtMessages.Text.Substring(i)

        If rtMessages.TextLength() = textLength Then
            rtMessages.Clear()
            rtMessages.AppendText("[buffer trimming algorithm failed]")
            Exit While
        End If

        textLength = rtMessages.TextLength()
    End While

    ' Scroll down
    rtMessages.SelectionStart = rtMessages.TextLength()
    rtMessages.ScrollToCaret()

End Sub
```

Comment: A viable workaround in some cases, I suppose, but my buffer was huge; this also breaks the current scroll position.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit , is the scroll position not being reset by the `rtMessages.SelectionStart = rtMessages.TextLength()` and `rtMessages.ScrollToCaret()`? In my tests it was scrolling fine. What size buffer where you using?

Comment: I actually don't have the code now so it's speculation from memory, but my memory says that replacing the whole text buffer with new text loses the old scroll position. Is this not so? The buffer would be up to 10KB or so IIRC.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit , you are correct that it would set the caret to the top, however, the last 2 lines of your code force the caret (and the scroll position) to the bottom

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot my own question. I did say it would always be scrolled to the bottom. I still don't like replacing the whole buffer, though.